# Inno Setup error on SetupIconFile - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by other process

Tags: c#, wpf, inno-setup

For some reason I'm getting the error below when setting up the `Setup Icon` for the installer.

ERROR:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by other process

Script:

```
#define MyAppName "MyApp 4.0"
#define MyAppVersion "4.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "Some Company Name"
#define MyAppURL "http://www.example.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "MyApp.exe"

[Setup]
AppId={{F89D3454-5DFD-471B-B4A1-D49DFB8637B0}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\MyApp App
DisableDirPage=yes
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
LicenseFile=C:\Users\Some Folder\MyApp-License.txt
OutputDir=C:\Users\Some Folder\Installers
OutputBaseFilename=Setup-MyApp
SetupIconFile=C:\Users\Some Folder\Logos\logo.ico
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\UserName\SomeFolder\MyApp\bin\Release\MyApp.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\UserName\SomeFolder\MyApp\bin\Release\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\UserName\SomeFolder\MyApp\bin\Release\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\UserName\SomeFolder\MyApp\bin\Release\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\UserName\SomeFolder\MyApp\bin\Release\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\UserName\SomeFolder\MyApp\bin\Release\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\UserName\SomeFolder\MyApp\bin\Release\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\UserName\SomeFolder\MyApp\bin\Release\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\UserName\SomeFolder\MyApp\bin\Release\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\UserName\SomeFolder\MyApp\bin\Release\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\UserName\SomeFolder\MyApp\bin\Release\Newtonsoft.Json.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\UserName\SomeFolder\MyApp\bin\Release\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\UserName\SomeFolder\MyApp\bin\Release\Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\UserName\SomeFolder\MyApp\bin\Release\Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Themes.Aero.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\UserName\SomeFolder\MyApp\bin\Release\Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Themes.Metro.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\UserName\SomeFolder\MyApp\bin\Release\Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Themes.VS2010.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\UserName\SomeFolder\MyApp\bin\Release\Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\UserName\SomeFolder\MyApp\bin\Release\Xceed.Wpf.MyAppkit.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{commonprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

If I comment out line `SetupIconFile=C:\Users\Some Folder\Logos\logo-name.ico` it compiles fine without errors.

Any idea what can I do to be able to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Do you get the error if you use a different icon?  Maybe the sample included with InnoSetup: `SetupIconFile=C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\Examples\setup.ico`

Comment: The `Examples` folder in the Program Files does not contain an .ico file, in fact I couldn't find it any where. I did create a different .ico file and tried it but I got the same error. Thanks.

Comment: My mistake, I must've copied one in before.  If you're tried multiple icone, you might look at a tool like LockHunter (https://lockhunter.com) to see what's locking that file.  You might also want to reboot the machine.  I'm compiling with various icons without any problem.

Comment: I installed lockhunter and check the `.ico` file and nothing seem to be locking it, it came as `"No processes locking this file or folder have been found"`. After trying lockhunter, I rebooted my computer a few times and on the third time it compiled fine, but only once, I tried it again and I got the error. I guess I will just keep rebooting until it works. I'm currently testing the installer that's why I need to run it multiple times otherwise one compile would be enough. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

An *.ico file consists of more than one lay-out (or grid) of a given picture.
Like 24*24 pixels, 48*48 pixels 64*64 pixels etc depending on what screen resolution being used.
Maybe one of the needed layers is absent or the entire .ico file is indeed locked.
Try Ico-FX to create an *.ico file of a BMP and use it in your script.
or extract an icon via an icon-extractor.

Whatever you do, use a short path, preferable with no spaces to begin with.

Inno Setup Docs suggest (at least) the following sizes:

16x16 32x32 48x48 64x64 and 256x256